# "My work has done" vs "my work has been done"

Tags: grammar, tenses

Please tell me that what is the difference between

> My work has done

and

> My work has been done

problem is with the use of has and has been

Comment: Consider a visit to our sister site for [ell.se]

Comment: The main difference is that the second will be considered a correct sentence by any proficient speaker of English. The first one will be seen as ungrammatical by most, if not all, in the same group.

Comment: The first should be: **My work is done** If you edit your question it has a better chance of staying open. Otherwise it will be closed as being off-topic.

Comment: 'My work is done' is grammatical, but sounds dated unless 'padded' ('My work is done by ten highly-paid chimpanzees while I am on vacation'). You can force a grammatical usage (as usual): 'I'm not sure, but I think my work has increased significantly.' ... '_My_ work has done.'

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The user has vanished, I'd suggest closing/deleting this question.

Comment: @Edwin “My work (here) is done” is not dated at all—it’s quite common and colloquial. Your forced grammatical usage I would label quite forcedly grammatical. No matter what the circumstances, I would never in normal conversation say, “_My_ work has done”, but “_My_ work (sure) has”.

Comment: @Janus: Yes – you automatically add padding – “My work here is done”.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not necessarily—I just added there _here_ in parentheses to show what use of the phrase I was talking about. “My work is done” works just fine for me on its own, too.

Comment: And it sounds dated, not too idiomatic, to me. Most people would use 'I've finished [my work]'. A Google Ngram for 'My work is done' shows a distinct lessening in popularity.

Answer (score 2):

My work has done does not really make sense grammatically, at least not as a complete sentence. It would need an ending to that- what has my work done? My work has been done, however, is a complete sentence. It means that someone has done my work (probably me) as opposed to my work doing something (which is what "my work has done" means).